# CMD command or script for inserting a string before closing tag ">" for each line that has a specific tag name

Tags: xml, cmd

I would like to find an easyer solution in inserting a string at the end of a tag (before the closing tag) in a xml file in windows.
This is a huge XML file with over 4000 lines.
At almost all lines there is an managedObject tag, and at the end i would like to insert a string: `operation="create"`.
So it looks like this:

```
<managedObject class="blabla" ... id="1234">
```

..and want to make it like this:

```
<managedObject class="blabla" ... id="1234" operation="create">
```

As I said the XML file is huge, and not all lines have managedObject tags.
I only want to insert the string were the managedObject tags are.

Up till now i did it manually..but it takes a lot of time..

Comment: That's a really technical description of what you want. Pity it light on detail.

Comment: ..sorry, forgot to add the code snippets and the tags were not showing, i have edited.

Comment: Powershell script and XPath is a best way IMO.

Comment: What programming languages do you know?

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with @montonero that handling xml files with xml tools is the way to do it,
... but a quick hack for one time things with a RegEx can save time.

Here this PowerShell one liner using RegEx'es with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should do (presuming utf8 encoding):

```
(gc .\sample.xml -raw -enc utf8) -replace '(?<=\<managedobject)(?!.*?operation="create")([^\>]*?)\>','$1 operation="create">'|Set-Content new_sample.xml -enc utf8
```

Where

- `(?<=\<managedobject)` is a zerolength lookbehind assertion matching the begin of the tag.
- `(?!.*?operation="create")` is a zerolength negative lookahead assertion assuring not inserting `operation="create"` twice
- `([^\>]*?)` is a capture group to keep before the insertion.

Used on a sample file containing the above question yields:

```
I would like to find an easyer solution in inserting a string at the end of a tag (before the closing tag) in a xml file in windows.
This is a huge XML file with over 4000 lines.
At almost all lines there is an managedObject tag, and at the end i would like to insert a string: operation="create".
So it looks like this:

<managedObject class="blabla" ... id="1234" operation="create">

..and want to make it like this:

<managedObject class="blabla" ... id="1234" operation="create">

As I said the XML file is huge, and not all lines have managedObject tags. I only want to insert the string were the managedObject tags are.

Up till now i did it manually..but it takes a lot of time..
```